# Is the following sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammar

> The Eisenberger team found that emotional pain activates the opposing reactions of these areas activate in exactly the same way.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not grammatical.

Comment: It's almost certainly a typo, where *activate* should be ***activated***. (And I'd also change *these* to *those*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: "_activate should be activated_" Which "activate"? Would you mind editing the complete sentence?

Comment: There is only one *activate* in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not grammatically correct.

It seems to be a simple mistake. The author began with a sentence like

> Opposing reactions activate in the same way.

Then rephrased to say

> Emotional pain activates opposing reactions in the same way.

But forgot to remove the second "activate" from after the phrase "opposing reactions", this seems to give a clause with two main finite verbs, which is not possible in English Grammar. Just remove the second "activate" and the sentence is correct.